# MS ACCESS SQL grouping and counting zeros

Tags: sql, ms-access

Need help with creating a SQL statement for the following:

Basically, we have supervisors that go out and do tests on employees. These tests are recorded online and are exported to an access database.

The tests are grouped into categories. So, for example test #’s 101, 102 & 103 are grouped in category 1 test #’s 112, 113 & 114 are grouped into category 2 and so on.

Each supervisor is required to do a certain number in each category.

There is a table that has information about each test number and which category they fall into and another table that has details on the categories.

I need a report to show how many tests in each category supervisors have done each month, but I need to show a 0 count if no tests were entered for a particular month.

I was able to get the counts using vba by looping thru each category then looping thru each test number then counting each test number that was complete but it takes almost 30 seconds for each supervisor (way too long with over 500 supervisors).

I hope I am explaining this correctly and I am hoping that you might have an easy solution for this.

**Example Report that need to be created**

```
Supervisor: Harvey Sample ( 0084568 )

01/20     Category 1:  5 Tests
01/20     Category 2:  0 Tests
01/20     Category 3:  8 Tests
01/20     Category 4:  2 Tests
01/20     Category 5:  4 Tests

02/20     Category 1:  2 Tests
02/20     Category 2:  6 Tests
02/20     Category 3:  3 Tests
02/20     Category 4:  0 Tests
02/20     Category 5:  5 Tests
```

Completed Tests are stored in this table

```
SPARTN_Livefeed1
Sheet ID         Date          Test Number          Supervisor ID
OB-1234          1/1/2020         101                 806855
OB-5678          1/1/2020         101                 806855
OB-9877          1/1/2020         112                 806855
OB-5644          1/1/2020         123                 806855
OB-5644          1/1/2020         123                 806855
```

```
REF_TestCatalog_tbl
ID          TestId          TestDesc          TestCategory          StartDate          EdnDate
1             101            Stopping              1                 12/1/2019
2             112            Delay                 2                 12/1/2019
3             123            Documents             3                 12/1/2019
4             134            Radio                 4                 12/1/2019




REF_TestCategory_tbl
ID        CategoryID          CategoryDesc          StartDate          EndDate   
1             1               Signals               12/1/2019
2             2               Speed                 12/1/2019
3             3               Equipment             12/1/2019
4             4               Operation             12/1/2019



Expected Results
CategoryID          TestofficerID          Actuals          ComplianceMonth
1                   806855                 2                 1/1/2020
2                   806855                 1                 1/1/2020
3                   806855                 3                 1/1/2020
4                   806855                 0                 1/1/2020
```

Comment: Sample data as test would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @supervisor varchar[50];
set @supervisor ='Harvey Sample'

select date, 'Category 1', (select count(*) from supervisor_tests sc where st.date = sc.date and sc.category = 'Category 1' and sc.supervisor = @supervisor) 
from supervisor_tests st where supervisor = @supervisor
union
select date, 'Category 2', (select count(*) from supervisor_tests sc where st.date = sc.date and sc.category = 'Category 2' and sc.supervisor = @supervisor) 
from supervisor_tests st where supervisor = @supervisor
order by date
```

add more unions for each category. Can also do a range of dates if you want it to be monthly aggregate.

Comment: Just join the tables (or perhaps make a temp table) and change out the field names and it should still work fine